# Green Lantern Corps and Krypton

Tags: comics, dc, superman, green-lantern, krypton

I was wondering if the issue of *"why the Green Lantern Corps did not do anything to save Krypton"* has come up in the DC Universe.

I don't really know enough about the Green Lantern mythology to know if saving any and every planet is something they are supposed to do, or if they have a more specific goal. This is just a question that's been buzzing in my brain for a couple of days.

Comment: If you're interested I think you can still [read Green Lantern #1 Free Online](http://studiowell.com/ComicsOnline/2011/09/29/read-green-lantern-1-free-online)

Comment: I am interested, but I think they are doing maintence on these site. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's [Tomar-Re](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Tomar-Re_(New_Earth))'s Space Sector!

[image]

Tomar was a scientist before joining the [Green Lantern Corps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps) and becoming the Green Lantern of [Space Sector 2813](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Sector_2813).  Here's an excerpt from his [Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomar-Re#Fictional_character_biography):

> Tomar's most famous mission while serving in the Corps dealt with the
>   planet Krypton. Krypton, a planet in sector 2813, was growing
>   increasingly unstable. It was due to explode, caused by internal
>   pressures deep inside the planet's core. Tomar-Re sought to use a rare
>   compound called stellarium to absorb some of the tectonic pressure,
>   thus saving the Kryptonians. He gathered the compound, and was en
>   route to Krypton when a yellow solar flare blinded him, and forced him
>   to drop the stellarium. He quickly recovered, but discovered he was
>   blind. He gathered what little stellarium he could without his sight,
>   and proceeded towards Krypton. He was closing in when his vision
>   started to clear. The first thing he saw upon his sight returning was
>   Krypton exploding. The Guardians recovered Tomar and brought him back
>   to Oa, where he healed and rested.

[Tomar-Re](http://www.comicvine.com/tomar-re/4005-10449/) was a mentor to [Hal Jordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hal_Jordan) and died during [Crisis on Infinite Earths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths) when the Central Power Battery that charged all of the Green Lanterns' rings was attacked by the Anti-Monitor.  His son, [Tomar-Tu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomar-Tu), is now [GL of Space Sector 2813](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomar-Tu#Green_Lantern_of_Sector_2813).